# jaxb, unmarshal exception

Tags: java, сериализация, serializable, jaxb, unserialize

Пытаюсь unmarshal ить xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CreateSmth>
............
</CreateSmth>
```

в следующий класс

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "CreateSmth")
public class CreateSmth
    extends BasicRQType
    implements Serializable
{
```

и получаю ошибку:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"CreateSmth"). Expected elements are (none)

at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:740)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:262)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:257)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:124)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1148)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:573)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:555)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:168)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
at ___.XmlUtils.xml2object(XmlUtils.java:22)
at ___.parseXml(CreateSmth.java:44)
at ___.MyClass.method(MyClass.java:24)
at ?.* Когда запускаем парсинг xml _______.xml(________.feature:6)
```

в чем может быть проблема? Возможно, в том классе (**BasicRQType**), от которого наследуется **CreateSmth**?

```
(public class BasicRQType implements Serializable без @XmlRootElement)
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код и добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки. Абсолютно непонятно к чему относится последняя строка текста вопроса.

Comment: Непонятно что происходит по обрывкам кода в вопросе. Добавьте в вопрос сам код по сериализации с примером использования.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, прошу прощения, я тут недавно.
Про последнюю сторку уточнила.
Mikhail Grebenev, добавила.